# How to Programatically cancel order in magento 2

Tags: php, magento2

If a customer placed an order of 3 different items with different quantities like

1. shirt 2 qty
2. Watch 1qty
3. pant  3qty

and cancels the order item at different times I have to set the state to order cancelled

here's my code can anyone please tell me where I am wrong

```
if (isset($_POST['order'])) {
         $_orderCollectionFactory = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory');

     $collection = $_orderCollectionFactory->create()

             ->addFieldToSelect('*')
             ->addFieldToFilter('status', ['neq' => 'cancelled']); 
foreach ($collectionFactory as $order)
        {
            $items = $order->getAllVisibleItems();
            foreach ($items as $items) {

                $totalitem = $totalitem + ($item['qty_canceled']);
                $itemcount = $order->getQtyOrdered();
               if ($itemcount == ($totalitem))
                 {
                    $order->setState("canceled");
                    $order->save();
                }

            }    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I have Solved the issue  for the above code

```
 $_orderCollectionFactory = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory');

     $collection = $_orderCollectionFactory->create()
             ->addFieldToSelect('*')
             ->addFieldToFilter('status', ['neq' => 'cancelled']); 
             
foreach ($collection as $order)
        {
            $items = $order->getAllVisibleItems();
            $totalitem=0;
            foreach ($items as $item) {

            //  echo '<pre>';print_r(get_class_methods($item));
            // die();
                 $totalitem = $totalitem + ($item['qty_canceled']);
                $itemcount = $order->getQtyOrdered();

                if ($itemcount == ($totalitem))
                 {
                    echo $order->getIncrementId();
                    $order->setState("canceled");
                    $order->setStatus("canceled");
                    $order->save();
                 }
            }    
    }
```